# Why are there no Definitions for "LogLevel" and "UseInternalLoghandler"?

Tags: dsharp+

i need help by progrmming my own Discord bot. I wantet to write in the Code "LogLevel = LogLevel.Debug, UseInternalLoghandler = true" but Visulas studio makes two errors. It says that there is no definition of LogLevel and UnseInternalLoghandler. Can somebody help me? Maybe i fogot a "using" + ..., but i dont know

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar error, and I managed to fix the `Loglevel.Debug` but can't fix `UseInterNalLogHandler`.

So for `LogLevel.Debug` you can use this.

- `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Debug`
- Or just `using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Debug` at the
  top of the code.

Sorry can't help with the `UseInternalLoghandler`.